# Multiple Quick Replies in Dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have begun using Google's Dialogflow (previously API.AI). I have seen there is an option to add 'Quick Replies'. However I only seem to be able to add one (see screenshot). I know that both Telegram and Facebook Messager allow multiple 'Quick Replies'.

How do I enable more replies? Do I need to alter any code?

Thanks in advance.

[image: OnlyOneOption]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can add more values in quick replies of api.ai. You just have to press `ctrl+Enter` if you want to go on adding more values. Please check out snap here. There is a limit of 20 characters per value & you can add up to 10 values/replies per element. There is one more restriction, you can have one Quick reply element per intent. Read more about this here, https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages

[image]

Comment: this is only for Facebook messenger

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Ctrl + Enter thing.. I think Google have to learn so much of user experience.. Their interface is fine and looks great, but it is so easy to get lost using their services :(