# Can we choose multiple options(Quick Replies) at once in chatbots and give the response accordingly

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a requirement, where I need to use Google Dialogflow to create a chatbot. Usecase is User can choose 2 or 3 buttons(i.e., Quick Replies) and the bot should respond the answer based on the selections of buttons. If anyone had done this kind of usecase, please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Quick Replies in Dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918857/multiple-quick-replies-in-dialogflow)

Comment: Sorry, the question which you shared is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why don't you create multiple quick replies aggregating your response options, e.g. "1) eat your cake", "2) have your cake", "3) eat and have your cake"? (Unfortunately, this will get messy if there are too many options.)